# safari set webkit-scrollbar will break word

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, safari

When I set the `-webkit-scrollbar` property, there is a difference in display between Chrome and Safari. Chrome will not break the text into a new line, but Safari will. I have set the `max-width` property for the text, but Safari does not follow the max-width. Here is the code.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="chart-tooltip">
      <div>
        <table cellspacing="0" >
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <div class="title-container">
                  <span class="icon"></span>
                  <span class="title">San Francisco</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="value">0</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <div class="title-container">
                  <span class="icon"></span>
                  <span class="title">San Francisco</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="value">0</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <div class="title-container">
                  <span class="icon"></span>
                  <span class="title">San Francisco</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="value">0</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <div class="title-container">
                  <span class="icon"></span>
                  <span class="title">San Francisco</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="value">0</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <div class="title-container">
                  <span class="icon"></span>
                  <span class="title">San Francisco</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="value">0</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </div>
  </body>
  <style>
    .chart-tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 12px;
      max-height: 64px;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .chart-tooltip::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 6px;
        height: 6px;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .chart-tooltip::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: #d1d5e6;
        border: solid 4px transparent;
        border-radius: 12px;
    }

    .title-container {
      line-height: 18px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      padding-top: 4px;
    }

    .icon {
      height: 5px;
      width: 11px;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 8px;
      background-color:#FF8F6C;
      border:1px solid #FF8F6C;
    }

    .title {
      max-width: 300px;
      word-break: break-all;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
    }

    .value {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-left: 16px;
    }
  </style>
</html>
```

codepen

https://codepen.io/DYS1230/pen/xxQwmEN

I want Safari to behave like Chrome and not break the text into a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

::-webkit-scrollbar is only supported if `overflow:scroll` is set.

See the below example.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

```css
.chart-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 12px;
  max-height: 64px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.chart-tooltip::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.chart-tooltip::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #d1d5e6;
  border: solid 4px transparent;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.title-container {
  line-height: 18px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.icon {
  height: 5px;
  width: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
  background-color:#FF8F6C;
  border:1px solid #FF8F6C;
}

.title {
  max-width: 300px;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.value {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="chart-tooltip">
      <div>
        <table cellspacing="0" >
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <div class="title-container">
                  <span class="icon"></span>
                  <span class="title">San Francisco</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="value">0</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <div class="title-container">
                  <span class="icon"></span>
                  <span class="title">San Francisco</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="value">0</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <div class="title-container">
                  <span class="icon"></span>
                  <span class="title">San Francisco</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="value">0</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <div class="title-container">
                  <span class="icon"></span>
                  <span class="title">San Francisco</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="value">0</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <div class="title-container">
                  <span class="icon"></span>
                  <span class="title">San Francisco</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="value">0</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/salman-1775/pen/poQjGrz